# YOLOV5 is not giving prediction on live webcam?

Tags: python, deep-learning, computer-vision, yolov5

Actually i have trained a yolov5 model with traffic sign dataset diamentions (1360,800) with size of each image is 600KB but when i do real-time prediction on laptop camera its note able to predict on those signs. The diamention of webcame image are (600,450) with size 280KB does this problem due to the size or diamention of the image.
One thing to keep in mind i have no GPU,CPU in local pc i have trained model on colab. and its working fine on image for test in dataset with high size and diamentions.

This YOLOV5 trained model is working on test data of their own dataset but its not working on my captured image or live webcame of my pc.

Comment: Yes you are right, the model was trained on a different image shapes, thats why you need to lower the resolution of your training images or decrease the resoulition of your camera :)   the yolov5 backbone as an input layer which is declared before the training therfore the model can read and analyze the input better if the images given him is in the same size he was trained on.

Comment: Okay mark it was halpfull